# Using "the" in a compound subject

Tags: articles

> 1. The Software Engineers and the Electrical Engineers will work together in the project.
> 2. The Software Engineers and Electrical Engineers will work together in the project.

Which of these two sentences is correct, and why?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd get rid of even more of the redundancy:

> The software and electrical engineers will work together **on** the project.

These are generic job titles, so there's no need to capitalize them.

They're working "on" a project, not "in" it.

You could also add the word "both".

> Both the software and electrical engineers will work together on the project.

Regardless, to address your actual question, the first "the" is transitive so the second is not necessary.

Comment: 'Both' adds nothing to the meaning when the sentence says the two groups of engineers will work together...

Comment: (The _first_ "the" is transitive, so the _second_ "the" is unnecessary)

Comment: @ErikKowal Sure it does. It acts to emphasize the statement.

Comment: Why would such an emphasis be needed here?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, the two `the`'s are needed to avoid ambiguity.

Compare:

- I met the captain and wicketkeeper.
- I met the captain and the wicketkeeper.

In the first sentence, you're talking about one person, who's the captain as well as the wicketkeeper of the team.

In the second sentence, you're talking about two different people.

To avoid ambiguity, it's a good practice to use two `the`'s, even though it might seem redundant sometimes.

Comment: Both your variants are also ambiguous: without more context, we still cannot be sure whether one person or two is being described. A more effective sort of disambiguating construction is needed, such as "I met both the captain and the wicketkeeper" (if they are two individuals) or "I met the captain, who is also the wicketkeeper" (if they are the same person).

Comment: @ErikKowal. Disagree. #2 isn't ambiguous at all. #1 is definitely less ambiguous when phrased your way, but grammatically, it implies I met one person without a doubt. Anyway, I'm not pointing out the best way to disambiguate it. I'm pointing out the ambiguity itself when used as is, and what the grammatical implications are.